# Cross-correlation of two non-stationary time series?

Tags: time-series, cross-correlation, stationarity

I wish to test the cross-correlation of two time series to measure how "instantaneously related" my time series are. However, I am not quite sure if I should difference my time series first, and make them stationary? Because they obviously aren't:

[image]

[image]

And the cross-correlation I get is very different if I difference my time series, or not.

Cross-correlation `cff()` on original non-differenced data:

[image]

Cross-correlation `cff()` on differenced data with `diff()`:

[image]

Which one is right? Am I supposed to use `cff()` on stationary data only? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

why don't you post your data and I will try and help you. Box and Jenkins suggested pre-filtering where the differencing operator identified as part of the ARIMA process was used as part of the filter to identify model form via the resultant cross-correlation .    See https://web.archive.org/web/20160216193539/https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/75/ AND  http://www.math.cts.nthu.edu.tw/download.php?filename=569_fe0ff1a2.pdf&dir=publish&title=Ruey+S.+Tsay-Lec1 AND http://autobox.com/cms/images/dllupdate/TFFLOW.png . However if both X and Y are I(1) .. it is still possible that Y and X can related without any differencing at all which suggests that alternative approaches to incorporating differencing in the TF model or not be on the table.