# Using Index (ratio) for time series analysis

Tags: time-series, forecasting, ratio

I am doing a multivariate time series analysis. However, one of my time series is the Productivity **Index**. The time series consist of quarterly data from 1971 to 2015. The index is such that 2010 = 1, meaming that the average value of all four quarters in 2010 is equal to 1. The remaining values for every quarter are expressed according to the index value.

[image]

**Can I proceed with the time series?**

**What implications do the index values have on my results?**

Comment: Why did you include the [tag:prediction], [tag:garch] and [tag:cointegratoin] tags? Your question does not seem to indicate they would be relevant.

Comment: because I found that these two time series are cointegrated, there is at most one cointegrating equation. I am planing to use use these time series for prediction. I did a univariate prediction on GDP using the GARCH ARMA model. I am sorry if i did something wrong, i am still figuring out how it works here...

Comment: You might want to see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315206/cross-correlation-of-two-non-stationary-time-series/315350#315350

Comment: @Dana, no worries, I just wanted to find out why you included the tags and whether they were relevant. I think the connection with GARCH and cointegration is perhaps too weak to include these tags, but you can edit your post to say you are going to forecast your series, then the [tag:forecasting] tag is fine.